# Insert image into table cell in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, html-table, cell

I want to insert images to the new cell just created. How can I do it? Can anyone guide me in doing it?
Here's my code to insertcells:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function displayResult()
    {
    var firstRow=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0];
    var x=firstRow.insertCell(-1);
    x.innerHTML="New cell"
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <table id="myTable" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>First cell</td>
        <td>Second cell</td>
        <td>Third cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert cell</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

All I want is to insert image in the cell created.

Comment: You can put some text in you `td` using `innerHTML` but you can't put there an `img` tag?

Comment: @Teemu Yes .. exactly..

Comment: I don't quite understand, what's the difference if you wrote `"<img src='myImageURL' />"` instead of `"New cell"`?

Answer (score 23):

You can create the image element and append it to the new cell:

```
function displayResult()
{
    var firstRow=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0];
    var x=firstRow.insertCell(-1);
    x.innerHTML="New cell";

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "link to image here";
    x.appendChild(img);
}
```

Beware of building the raw HTML for the image, if you do it that way you'll need to make sure that you escape the `src` and any other attributes.

Comment: This tool might be useful for escaping html attributes: http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/quick-escape/default.php

Answer (score 8):

Simply set the inner HTML of the new cell to the HTML of an img element, with whatever src or attributes you wish.

```
function displayResult()
{
    var firstRow=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0];
    var x=firstRow.insertCell(-1);
    x.innerHTML="<img src='myImageURL' alt='hello'/>";
}
```

Comment: Hey this worked for me! I like the minimal number of lines too.

Answer (score -1):

```
 function displayResult()
    {
   document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].innerHTML="your image";
    }
```

may be this can help,dynamicism can be achieved later on,just try if it works for now?

Comment: This displays the name of the image file. It does not put the actual image out there.