# Populating HTML Table with Images Tag and String Challenged?

Tags: javascript, html, image, html-table, populate

Having figured out how to update images in tables when using a row/column indicator - I began working on my next learning stage, populating a sample table with data set in two local arrays.

I was OK as long as I replaced only a new file name, but once I wanted to change the sizing information I had evaluation errors from JavaScript.

My errors seemed to be a combination of where to place the HTML ending tag '>' and - possibly- string issues with nesting single and double quotes (' and ") .

Below is my example that I got working. I imagine I might eventually set some of these strings into constants that are then concatenated together when replacing the values in the table's

Notes of Interest to Me: 
1) I forgot to put in cell ending "/td " and yet it all seems to go OK. I wonder if that could cause some kind of unexpected challenge down the road.

2)I think I could use the inserting cell example I wrote about in a previous answer-my-own-question 
[Basic Table Manipulation: How to change and Insert images in HTML Table using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271337/newbie-basic-table-manipulation-how-to-change-and-insert-images-in-html-table-u/38271339#38271339)

to avoid having the little empty table come up before I click the button. However.... I would not really use the buttons in a real app. I would populate the table upon loading the page.... However inserting the rows one at a time,  would be much cleaner, as it would give better potential for having a variable number of questions (I have one question per row in the table). If I setup the table to always be say... 10 and only fill up 5 borders are going to look unattractive. And also inserting would just be more clean and programatic!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table id="QuestionsAnswersTable">

<tr>
<td>

 <td>
  <td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
 <td>
  <td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
 <td>
  <td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
 <td>
  <td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
 <td>
  <td>
</tr>


</table>
<br>
<p> Using table name, row column numbers, NO ID's</p>
<button onclick="changeImages()">Setup Image Cells   -  </button>


<button onclick="changeTexts()">Change Text cells</button>


<script>
// 
//http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp
// Various helpful urls
//http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/186129-how-put-images-    
table-cells-using-javascript.html

//http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978296/insert-image-into-table-cell-
in-javascript


//http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_tr_cells.asp


//option 1
// put each object together from////
// then when I go to populate the table.... hummmm
// var flower1Object = {picture: };



//option 2
// Put the column 0's into photosArray
// Then put the column 1's into commonArray
// This means that the data will not be associated until it appears in the     
table

var photosArray = ["img/0.Chilopsis_linearis_arcuata.jpg",
"img/1.Desert_five-spot.jpg",
"img/2.Desert-Globemalllow.jpg",
"img/3.Mojave_Aster-1.jpg",
"img/4.WebVuHedgehogCalicoCactusInBloomJoshuaTreeLaurelShimer.jpg",
"img/5.Cholla2.jpg"
  ];
var commonArray = [
"Desert Willow",
"Desert Five Spot",
"Desert Globemallow",
"Mojave Aster",
"Hedgehog Cactus or Calico Cactus",
"Cholla or Jumping Cactus"

 ];


function changeImages()
    // swap one image for another, NOT using id for the row/column
{

var testMe = ' <img src="img/0.Chilopsis_linearis_arcuata.jpg" ';
var testMePart2ALT =  " alt='Desert Willow' ";

var testMePart3ALT =  '  height="550" width="450"style="clear: left" > ';

 var testMePart1And2And3ALT = testMe + testMePart2ALT + testMePart3ALT;


      document.getElementById("QuestionsAnswersTable").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = testMePart1And2And3ALT;




}


function changeTexts()
// swap text for other text, NOT using id for the row/column
{


document.getElementById("QuestionsAnswersTable").rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML 
    = commonArray[0];
}

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code shows what I got working. I broke up the tags and quoted strings into 3 strings in *function changeImages()*, then concatenated them, to figure out how to make the replacement string with filename and sizing come together.

[image: initial page with tiny unpopulated table]

[image: results page - populated with one image and one text]